# Typing issue when mapping a useState object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

I am creating a simple modal form where you create a team, and you can assign existing users to said team. This is the relevant part of the modal;

```
export default function CreateTeamModal() {
const [memberData, setMemberData] = useState([{}]);
const users = useUsers();


return (
      <Modal>
              <Box
                  component="form"
                  sx={style}
                  noValidate
                  onSubmit={onSave}
                  autoComplete="off"
              >
                      <FormControl>
                          <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-chip-label">Members</InputLabel>
                          <Select
                              labelId="demo-multiple-chip-label"
                              id="demo-multiple-chip"
                              multiple
                              value={memberData.name}
                              onChange={handleMemberChange}
                              input={<OutlinedInput id="select-multiple-chip" label="Members" />}
                              renderValue={(selected) => (
                                  <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', gap: 0.5 }}>
                                      {selected.map((value) => (
                                          <Chip key={value} label={value} />
                                      ))}
                                  </Box>
                              )}
                          >
                              {users.map((user) => {
                                return(
                                  <MenuItem
                                      key={user.id as number}
                                      value={user} 
                                  >
                                      {user.name}
                                  </MenuItem>
                                )
                              })}
                          </Select>
                      </FormControl>
                  </div>
              </Box>
          </Modal>
          </>
  );
}
```

useUsers is a custom hook defined like so;

```
export const useUsers = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let subscribed = true;
    let apiClient = new APIClient();
    apiClient.getUser().then((response) => {
        if (subscribed) {
        setUsers(response);
        }
    });

    return () => {
        subscribed = false
    };
  }, []);

  return users;
};
```

Obviously this implementation doesn't work here, but the users.map is working elsewhere. Now, if I do something like this;

```
function returnThis(a) {
    return a;
}

var returnedUsers = returnThis(users);

{returnedUsers.map((user) => {
  return(
   <MenuItem
     key={user.id as number}
     value={user} 
    >
   {user.name}
   </MenuItem>
  )
})}
```

Then I get no issues with the map. Which area(s) am I going wrong with, and how should I fix them?

Comment: *doesn't work here* - what else happens? How do you know that it's not working?

Comment: The mapped users object gets no overload matches this call; Type 'String | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Key | null | undefined'.

Comment: Could you please show `User` type declaration?